# How to merge same sizes of arrays to one array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have several arrays which have same size like below:

```
@m1= (1,1,0,1);
@m2= (0,1,1,1);
@m3= (0,1,1,0);
@m4= (1,1,0,0);
```

The question is how can I put it in one array like this?

```
@m = (
      [1,1,0,1],
      [0,1,1,1],
      [0,1,1,0],
      [1,1,0,0]
     );
```

Comment: The question is, do you want to copy the arrays, or create references?

Comment: A better question is why do you have 4 separate arrays in the first place?

Comment: I want to copy the arrays

Answer (score 7):

**Edit:** Since you want to copy the arrays (as per your comment), then I would do this--

```
my @m = ( [ @m1 ], [ @m2 ], [ @m3 ], [ @m4 ] );
```

See [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for more information.

**Original answer:**

If you want to flatten them into one array:

```
my @m = ( @m1, @m2, @m3, @m4 );
```

If you want an array of arrayrefs:

```
my @m = ( \@m1, \@m2, \@m3, \@m4 );
```

Example:

```
use Data::Dumper;                                                                                                                                                                                          

my @m1= (1,1,0,1);                                                                                                                                                                                         
my @m2= (0,1,1,1);                                                                                                                                                                                         
my @m3= (0,1,1,0);                                                                                                                                                                                         
my @m4= (1,1,0,0);                                                                                                                                                                                         

my @m = ( @m1, @m2, @m3, @m4 );                                                                                                                                                                            
warn Dumper( \@m );                                                                                                                                                                                        

my @m_again = ( \@m1, \@m2, \@m3, \@m4 );                                                                                                                                                                  
warn Dumper( \@m_again );
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          1,
          1,
          0,
          1,
          0,
          1,
          1,
          1,
          0,
          1,
          1,
          0,
          1,
          1,
          0,
          0
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          [
            1,
            1,
            0,
            1
          ],
          [
            0,
            1,
            1,
            1
          ],
          [
            0,
            1,
            1,
            0
          ],
          [
            1,
            1,
            0,
            0
          ]
        ];
```

Answer (score 6):

You would do either of these things:

```
push @m, \@m1, \@m2,  ...       # references, using the same memory address
push @m, [ @m1 ], [ @m2 ], .... # making copies, placing them in anonymous arrays
```

This will create a two-dimensional array, which is what you have described in your question and I assume you want. Of course, you don't need to use `push`, but can use any way to manipulate an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
my @m = ( \@m1, \@m2, \@m3, \@m4 );
```

but you should probably have avoided putting them into separate arrays to begin with.

---

For example,

```
my @m1 = (1,1,0,1);
my @m2 = (0,1,1,1);
...
my @m = ( \@m1, \@m2, \@m3, \@m4 );
```

can be written as

```
my @m = (
   [1,1,0,1],
   [0,1,1,1],
   ...
);
```

---

For example,

```
my @m1 = f();
my @m2 = g();
...
my @m = ( \@m1, \@m2, \@m3, \@m4 );
```

can be written as

```
my @m;
$m[0] = [ f() ];
$m[1] = [ g() ];
...
```

or

```
my @m;
push @m, [ f() ];
push @m, [ g() ];
...
```